# How can I clean my hard disk?

Tags: disk

I started the Ubuntu trial from a CD, but can't subsequently install Ubuntu
because 'something' (probably from a previous attempt) is on the hard disk,
it's not a partition. Now I simply want to reformat the whole disk, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media and select **Try Ubuntu without installing**, once on the **Ubuntu Live desktop** open **GParted** from the dash. Click on **Device** on the top menu. Now click on **Create Partition Table**. Select `gpt` when you have an UEFI based BIOS. Select `msdos` when you have legacy (Master Boot Record) based BIOS. Click **Partition** -> **New** to create one or more partitions. Here you find a presentation I made to see how it works -> [gparted-create-partitions](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Vc5-6--Y0DA1Xa5dc36NTdVZezbCRl0omomPgEw7f4M/edit#slide=id.p).

[image]